# flow sensor based machine overflowing and not aligning to datasheet logic

Tags: arduino, sensors, arduino-c++

So I've got two problems.

1. I had a flow control machine for which I had the code below. In this code I could set how many ml of water I needed to let pass basis the calculation derived from the [datasheet](http://www.mantech.co.za/datasheets/products/yf-s201_sea.pdf). Since I am setting it to 750ml, then for a 600L/H pump it should mean I should let pass 369 pulses and then stop flow, but I am having to set it at 1910 pulses to fill the 750 ml bottle. Why is that? Could the reverse flux from solenoid switch be affecting the sensor readings.
2. When I click the button again an overflow happens. If I click it mid flow, then again overflow happens. But when I switch the system off and switch it back on then it works fine once again before overflowing again. How to correct the code to prevent that?

Below is the code...

```
volatile int flow_frequency; // Measures flow sensor pulses
// Calculated litres/hour
 float vol = 0.0,l_minute;
unsigned char flowsensor = 10; // Sensor Input
unsigned long currentTime;
unsigned long cloopTime;


int SolenoidPumpPin=11;

// constants won't change. They're used here to set pin numbers:
const int buttonPin = 12;     // the number of the pushbutton pin

// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status

void flow () // Interrupt function
{
   flow_frequency++;
}


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(SolenoidPumpPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SolenoidPumpPin, HIGH); //Switch Solenoid ON
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(flowsensor, INPUT);
   digitalWrite(flowsensor, HIGH); 

attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(flowsensor), flow, RISING); // Setup Interrupt
currentTime = millis();
   cloopTime = currentTime;


}

void loop() 
{



  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (buttonState == HIGH)
  {
    currentTime = millis();
   // Every second, calculate and print litres/hour
   if(currentTime >= (cloopTime + 1000))
   {
      cloopTime = currentTime; // Updates cloopTime
      // Pulse frequency (Hz) = 7.5Q, Q is flow rate in L/min.
      l_minute = (flow_frequency / 7.5); // (Pulse frequency x 60 min) / 7.5Q = flowrate in L/hour
      /*lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Rate: ");
      lcd.print(l_minute);
      lcd.print(" L/M");*/
      l_minute = l_minute/60;
      //lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      vol = vol +l_minute;
      /*lcd.print("Vol:");
      lcd.print(vol);
      lcd.print(" L");*/
      flow_frequency = 0; // Reset Counter
      float Vollume = (l_minute*cloopTime)/1000;
      //Serial.print(l_minute, DEC); // Print litres/hour
      //Serial.println(" L/Sec");

    while(flow_frequency<=1910)
    {
      digitalWrite(SolenoidPumpPin, LOW);
      Serial.println(Vollume);
      flow_frequency++;
  
    }
   }

    else {
      /*lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Rate: ");
      lcd.print( flow_frequency );
      lcd.print(" L/M");
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("Vol:");
      lcd.print(vol);
      lcd.print(" L");*/
    }
    digitalWrite(SolenoidPumpPin, HIGH);







 
  }  


}
```

Comment: your variable `flow_frequency` seems used too early, before being set properly

Comment: 600L/H is 10L/min and based on datasheet it generates pulses at 82Hz, that is 1/82Hz = 12.19ms, so that's 60/0.01219 = 4920 pulses/min, 10L = 4920 pulses, or 1L=492 pulses, or 1000/492=0.492 pulses/ml. All those are correct, and 750ml would be 750*0.492=369 pulses. But your sketch is not doing the same for the volume calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're incrementing flow_frequency (which is not a frequency btw) in your ISR and your while loop. That cannot work.

You're prematurely closing the valve. The only thing that stops you from basically closing the valve instantly is the delay introduced by Serial.println.